# open the flutter web (PWA) for certain browser

Tags: flutter, dart, browser, flutter-web

Hi I build a flutter web project, but I want to know, is there a way to allow user to open the link of flutter web in Chrome browser only, otherwise not allowed
so what I mean is... I have a link of flutter web: `www.example.com` and that link only can be accessed when user open it using Chrome, otherwise user is not allowed... is there a way or package that will help me to do that

Comment: did you see this , https://pub.dev/packages/platform_detect

Comment: I haven't tried that, I just know it from you... thank youu soo much for giving information...I will try it soon

Comment: Hi, @mohandesR I have been trying ```platform_detect``` and use statement if```browser.isChrome``` == true, user can open the page, else print("can not") and when I try it in my pc... it works correctly, but when I open it from my phone, I still can access another browser... am I doing wrong?

Comment: hi , @uyhaW I don't Know Honestly ... but I think you can ask this Question in Github library Issue .. the Library Writer knows better ... I am so sorry.again

Comment: Hi..@mohandesR that's okay, your information helps me so much...thank you very much for helping me